# VB.net Export form as PDF

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf

So I am making a documentation program for a physical therapy environment, and am trying to encorporate the ability to export the form with the data on it to a pdf or image of some sort. My form looks like this:

I have tried using the following code to create an image from it

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    ' Create a graphics object from the bitmap  
    Dim gfxScreenshot As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)
    ' Take a screenshot of the entire Form1  
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, Me.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    ' Save the screenshot   
    bmpScreenshot.Save("C:\Student.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

But every time it comes back as only part of the form.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you to drop `Me.Size` and use [Form.RestoreBounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.restorebounds(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
  Private Function GetFormImage(ByVal include_borders As Boolean) As Bitmap
        ' Make the bitmap.
        Dim wid As Integer = Me.Width
        Dim hgt As Integer = Me.Height
        Dim bm As New Bitmap(wid, hgt)
        ' Draw the form onto the bitmap.
        Me.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt))
        ' Make a smaller bitmap without borders.
        wid = Me.ClientSize.Width
        hgt = Me.ClientSize.Height
        Dim bm2 As New Bitmap(wid, hgt)
        ' Get the offset from the window's corner to its client
        ' area's corner.
        Dim pt As New Point(0, 0)
        pt = PointToScreen(pt)
        Dim dx As Integer = pt.X - Me.Left
        Dim dy As Integer = pt.Y - Me.Top
        ' Copy the part of the original bitmap that we want
        ' into the bitmap.
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm2)
        gr.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, New Rectangle(dx, dy, wid, hgt), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        Return bm
    End Function
```

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d258c2b-64b9-431f-9df8-398a7866de40/vbnet-save-windows-form-as-an-image-getformimage?forum=vbgeneral

And then call the function as so:

```
GetFormImage(*True to include the borders*).Save("C:\Student.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: For the GetFormImage(*True to include the borders*).Save("C:\Student.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg), the first * gives an error saying expression expected?

Comment: You need to replace *True to include the borders* with either True or False, depending on whether you want the borders of the form to be included in the image or not.